# Terraria: Desktop and PS4 Cross Platform

Tags: pc, ps4, terraria

I have the Desktop version of terraria and my boyfriend has terraria on PS4. Is it possible for us to play multiplayer.

Answer (score 5):

Sadly no there isn't any cross platform at the moment, but they are trying to get **all** platforms on the same update so they can do cross platform play. currently its Android With Iphone, Playstation With Xbox and pc with pc. :P

Answer (score 0):

There is no cross play between PC and console as of right now and with PC getting the last ever update there is a very small chance of there ever being cross play.

Looking it up though it looks like all consoles can play together but I couldn't find a certain answer on that.