# Can PC terraria play with Switch terraria, if they are on the same version

Tags: terraria, terraria-console

I want to play Terraria with some friends on console, but the newest Steam version is four updates away from the newest console version. I assume this  makes us incompatible, how should I go about this? Should I downgrade my client version, or is 1.4.3.2 compatible with 1.4.3.6?

Comment: First things first: You can't play with your console friends with Steam version. There's no crossplay(cross-platform) between PC and any of console edition.

Comment: But you can with mobile, are the modern console editions coded in C++?

Comment: No you can't. iOS and Android can crossplay, but iOS/Android cannot play with Steam version. I don't know if it's written in C++, but that doesn't change the situation, I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can tell, Android/iOS are the only cross platform the game supports.  There also seems to be conflicting results about whether PC and Mobile can play together (see below).

We have [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/361177/terraria-desktop-and-ps4-cross-platform) post about PS4 (console) and PC playing together, and the answer is no.

The [Wiki for Terraria](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Multiplayer#Notes) says

> Mobile and Desktop players can cross-play together if both downgrade to 1.4.0.5.

But this isn't verified.  The wiki then also states:

> Users of different platforms (Desktop version / PlayStation / Xbox One / Xbox 360 / Mobile version / Windows Phone) cannot play multiplayer games together. Only Android and iOS users can play cross-platform with each other.

I then found [this site](https://gameinstants.com/is-terraria-cross-platform/#Is_Terraria_Cross-platform_Xbox_PC) that lists all the cross platform support, and *everything* is a **no** except for Mobile and PC and Android/iOS. For mobile and PC, it states that they need to be running the same game version.

To summarize:

- Desktop *might* be able to play with Mobile players (conflicting sources)
- Android and iOS can play with one another
- Consoles are not cross platform enabled

  - A exception to this is PS4 and PS5 being "cross generational"